# Lower height of `v-data-table` inputs

Tags: html, css, vuetify.js, v-data-table

#### The Goal

I want to have a `v-data-table` that is editable and looks "nice".

#### The problem

Adding a `v-text-field` to make it editable also increases the row-height to a very eye unpleasing level
Original view:
[image: Kammer Original]
With v-text-field inputs
[image: Kammer inputs]

### The quesion

How can I decrease the row height to resemble the one without `v-text-fields`.

---

*As a Bonus*

Because I am quite new to this whole Front-End-Development-Kind-Of-Thing, how would I go about it identifying what is causing this "height issue"?

---

*PS: I've tried to add a JSFiddle but I cant even seem to be unable to figure out how to display the `v-data-table` correctly...

The basic draft can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/90gj28n3/3/)*

Comment: What's the status of the question? Were you able to figure it out? Then you could provide the answer yourself & accept it.

Comment: @NicolasDurant The status is, that work is keeps me moving ^^' I settled to just use a raw HTML `<input>` Tag wich I hardly consider the Solution

Answer (score 1):

Is it necessary for your table to be editable within the columns? How do you decide when to pass data back via request to your Backend? After the user left a field?

If it is not necessary to have the edit option within the table, I would just use the action buttons you already have in your table to trigger a modal in which you can edit the fields. This also allows you to have proper form control before a user can submit a request. There is also a Vuetify Codepen with an example how to do this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/nicolasdurant/pen/abBqwzz)

If it is necessary you should implement the `v-data-table` as `v-data-iterator` which is essentially the same functionality-wise, but allows for complete control over the look. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-iterators/

As to how to identify the problem with the `v-text-field` height you have to use your browser dev tools. You would then realise that the input has default paddings and margins but also a whole lot under the hood. It e.g. allocates space for error messages to pop up and for a label to go above the field.[image: Selector][image]

And how to fix your JSfiddle you can read in the getting started section of the vuetify documentation under CDN https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation/#usage-with-cdn.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "dense" property for Lower height of `v-data-table` inputs

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#dense